# Relationship between git commits and review items in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

When I `git commit` to my local branch, I like to commit one file at a time so that I can put in a commit message dedicated to that file only.  I just got done working on a task and I changed 8 files total, each of which was its own commit with its own commit message.

When I pushed my local branch into `Gerrit`, that created 8 code review items, not what I wanted.  I wanted a single review item with the 8 file changes bundled together.

**Q1:**  Does one git commit mean one Gerrit review item?

**Q2:**  How do I undo my push into Gerrit?

**Q3:**  How do I make it work so that I have individual file commits and commit messages but a single review item when it is pushed into Gerrit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1: Yes, a Gerrit review item is created for each commit that you push.

A2: To undo your push into Gerrit, use the "Abandon" button in Gerrit for each of your review items.

A3: You will need to *squash* your multiple commits into one commit before pushing to Gerrit. Use `git rebase -i` to rewrite your commits into one, then push to Gerrit.

Comment: So, IOW, there is no way to have dedicated commit messages per file committed in a multi-file commit, is that correct?

Comment: I did abandon all the reviews in Gerrit but when i did `git rebase -i <mylocalbranch>`, it didn't show anything to rebase.  Could it be because I had already pushed the local branch?

Comment: @amphibient: The argument to `rebase -i` is where to *start* rebasing from. If you name your local branch, then there are no following commits to rebase, so there is nothing to do. Try `git rebase -i HEAD~10` if you want to squash the last 8 commits.

Comment: When you squash the commits, you can combine all your per-file commit messages into the one commit message for the squashed commits. So you don't have to lose any information.

Comment: The answer totally fits your questions. However I'm wondering about your workflow with the commit per file. I'd say that if it's one change spanning multiple files (which have to be merged either all or nothing) then it should be a single commit. If it's multiple, atomic changes, then doa commit for each of them (and also review them individually).